# How to map multiple locations in an Excel Map chart

Tags: excel, dictionary, charts

So I have a table in Excel with 2 columns of cities and two columns of the sales of each city. I would like to plot both columns in the Map chart with different colours. But Excel will only plot the first 2 columns of cities and sales even though I set the range to the full table. Is it possible to add the second row of cities too?

[image]

Comment: Using VBA... we can use UNION function two combine two different columns & pass that as one in the chart...

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if it will work for you in Excel's Map... But in simple bar plot I tried... & It is doable to fetch data from multiple columns using simple comma separator...

e.g. Values from column C&D can be reference as:

```
=(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$4,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5)
```

& their tags can be:

```
=(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$4,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4)
```

*If this doesn't work in your case then best I can think of is using VBA only then...*